# ListFragment retrieves wrong List items from Mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, tabs

I had this activity with 3 ListFragments as tabs("MEALS","DRINKS","DESSERT"} which all retrieved list items from their individual tables in mysql database and displayed on their respective tabs.ALL WAS GOOD.
Now i expanded the application to involve checkablelayouts,which went well,but the whole drama started when i added a customAdapter for each list fragment.When i run the app,the meals tab retrieves and displays not only its table contents,but also the contents of the Drinks tab.When i swipe to the drinks Tab,it displays nothing,when i swipe to the Dessert tab,it displays nothing.But when i swipe back to drinks,it displays contents of other tables and not his.What i'm saying is,everything is just mixed up.Non of the Tabs display their respective data anymore.
Here is the MealsFragment Activity which used to work well,before i added the Custom adapter

```
public class MealsFragment extends ListFragment {


    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mealsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_meals = "http://10.180.35.102/dbase_connect/get_all_meals.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MEALS = "meals";
    private static final String TAG_MID = "mid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray meals = null;

    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_meals, container, false);



        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Hashmap for ListView
        mealsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Loading meals in Background Thread
        new LoadAllMeals().execute();

        // Get listview
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    }

    /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
       class LoadAllMeals extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



            /**
             * getting All Meals from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_meals, "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON response
                Log.d("All Meals: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // Meals found
                        // Getting Array of Meals
                        meals = json.getJSONArray(TAG_MEALS);

                        // looping through All meals
                        for (int i = 0; i < meals.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = meals.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_MID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                            String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                            map.put(TAG_MID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                            map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            mealsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } /*else {
                        // no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                NewProductActivity.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    */
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all meals
            //    pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */

                        String[] from = new String[] {TAG_MID,TAG_NAME,TAG_PRICE};
                        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.mid, R.id.name, R.id.price};

                      ListView listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                        ListAdapter adapter = new MealsCustomAdapter(
                                getActivity(), mealsList,
                                R.layout.meals_list_item, from,
                                to);
                        // updating listview
                        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }
                });

            }


}
}
```

and here is the MealsCustomAdapter

```
public class MealsCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    public MealsCustomAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, String>> data,
                         int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {

        super(context, data, resource, from, to);


    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // The item we want to get the view for
        // --
        // final Item item =  getItem(position);

        // Re-use the view if possible
        // --

        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (row == null) {
           // LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            row = li.inflate(R.layout.meals_list_item, parent, false);

        }

        return row;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    private LayoutInflater li;

    private class ViewHolder {
        public ViewHolder(View root) {
            ids = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.mid);
            names = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.name);
            prices = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.price);
            layout = (CheckableRelativeLayout) root.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }

        public TextView ids;
        public TextView names;
        public TextView prices;
        public CheckableRelativeLayout layout;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml layout for listfragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Xml layout for meals_list_items

```
<com.example.tabs.tablayout.CheckableRelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Meals id (mid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/itemCheckBox"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/itemCheckBox"
        android:textSize="9dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        />
    <!--  -->

</com.example.tabs.tablayout.CheckableRelativeLayout>
```

The other 2 tabs (DRINKS and DESSERT) have similar codes

The main issue here is just the fact that The Meals tabs does'nt display contents from MEALS table in database as it was before i added the custom adapter.
Please i will appreciate any help..Thanks

Comment: i think i've found the problem.I got it working,once i took out the statement  ListView listView = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.list);

Answer (score 1):

I am attaching sample code, hope it will help you to go through the problem, but this code is without the custom adapter. let's see, somehow it will help you. let me know any other help needed.`package com.desirecharge;

```
//Suhan Gorya
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;

        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.json.JSONArray;
        import org.json.JSONException;
        import org.json.JSONObject;

        import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ListAdapter;
        import android.widget.ListView;
        import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
        import android.widget.TextView;

        public class DTH extends ListFragment {
            TextView tvItemName;
            ListView lv;

            // Progress Dialog
            private ProgressDialog pDialog;

            // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

            // url to get all products list
            private static String url_all_products = "http://charge.com/Android/browse_plan.php";

            // JSON Node names
            private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
            private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
            private static final String TAG_PID = "price";
            private static final String TAG_NAME = "validity";
             View rootView;
            // products JSONArray
            JSONArray products = null;
            String msg= "No Plan Available";

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_products, container, false);
         /*     //  lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list); 
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading tarif plan");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            */  
                // Loading products in Background Thread
            //  new LoadAllProducts().execute();


              return rootView;

            }
            @Override
            public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                // Hashmap for ListView
                productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Loading meals in Background Thread
                new LoadAllProducts().execute();

                // Get listview
                lv = getListView();
                lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);

            }


            /**
             * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
             * */
            class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

                /**
                 * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
                 * */

                /**
                 * getting All products from url
                 * */
                protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    // getting JSON string from URL
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

                    // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                    Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                    try {
                        // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                        int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                        if (success == 1) {
                            // products found
                            // Getting Array of Products
                            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                            // looping through All Products
                            for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                                // Storing each json item in variable
                                String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                                // creating new HashMap
                                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                                productsList.add(map);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // no products found
                            // Launch Add New product Activity
                            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                    Test.class);
                            // Closing all previous activities
                            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return null;
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                    // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                    //pDialog.dismiss();
                    // updating UI from Background Thread
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            /**
                             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                             * */
                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                    getActivity(), productsList,
                                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                            TAG_NAME},
                                    new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name });
                            // updating listview
                            setListAdapter(adapter);
                        }
                    });

                }

        }
        }`
    all_product.xml`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Main ListView 
             Always give id value as list(@android:id/list)
        -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>`
    list_item.xml`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <!-- Name Label -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="6dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:textSize="17dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>`

    Let me know, if any help require.
```

Comment: this code is tested, let me know, if anyone faces any difficulties, i ll edit the answer. Thanks